# Magento 2.0 override core CofigurableProduct module block

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I want to change pricing calculation, for which i tried to override configurable block through preference, but it is not working

Here is my di.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Vendor\demo\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" />
```

Configurable.php:

```
class Configurable extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView {
$prices = [];
foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
$priceInfo = $product->getPriceInfo();
$product_weight=$product->load($product->getId())->getWeight();
 $prices[$product->getId()] =
 [
'oldPrice' => [
'amount' => $this->_registerJsPrice(
                        $priceInfo->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                    ),],
'basePrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->_registerJsPrice(
                        $priceInfo->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
                    ),
                ],
'finalPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->_registerJsPrice(
                        ((($product->getAttributeText('purity')/24)*100)/100)*(100000/10)*$product_weight
                    ),
                ]
 ];
    }
 return $prices;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` instead of overriding `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` instead of overriding `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` class. Because `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` is already overrided `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` class.